# Unable to use Hardware Acceleration for Radeon HD 6490M GPU

Tags: 12.04, radeon, hardware-acceleration

I've followed steps in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI/). Here is output of `vainfo` command:

```
me@hostname:~$ vainfo
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I have Catalyst 12.6 driver installed (from debs). I've fixed switchable graphics bug, using [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) (step 2). Also I tried to add `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=xvba LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/va/drivers` to `/etc/environment` and rebooted system, but the result was the same.

Comment: Please edit the original questions rather than add in information in comments.

Comment: Please answer your own question in the your answer section below and accept your answer so that the question is marked answered and others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Executing following will create a link to required file:

```
sudo ln -s xvba_drv_video.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
```

And...

```
me@hostname:~$ vainfo
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.32 (libva 1.0.15)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Yay! It works! :)